# Spring jdbc configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have been trying to implement a web service using spring. This webservice will provide data access to a mySQL database using JDBC. I am trying to not use any xml configuration files, so I have come across a problem trying to connect to the database.

I am following the tutorial: http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/ but I changed a few things along the way.

Now that I am trying to implement the connection with the database I get an error when trying to execute the tomcat instance, and I guess the problem is within the configurations.

Here follows some of my code:

Datasource configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("mySQL")
@PropertySource("classpath:/services.properties")
public class MySQLDataSourceConfiguration implements DataSourceConfiguration{

    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("dataSource.password"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("dataSource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("dataSource.user"));
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getPropertyAsClass("dataSource.driverClass",  Driver.class).getName());
    return dataSource;
    }
}
```

the file service.properties is where I keep my configurations for the database, so when I desire to change the database I will just have to change 4 fields.

The JDBCConfiguration class for the setup of the JDBCtemplate

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @PropertySource("classpath:/services.properties")
    @Import( { MySQLDataSourceConfiguration.class })
    public class JdbcConfiguration {

         @Autowired 
         private DataSourceConfiguration dataSourceConfiguration;

         @Inject 
         private Environment environment;

            @Bean
            public JdbcTemplate setupJdbcTemplate() throws Exception {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSourceConfiguration.dataSource());
            }

            @Bean
            public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
              return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
            }    
          }
```

Then there is the Repository, that recieves the template.

```
@Transactional
@Repository
@Qualifier("jdbcRepository")
public class JdbcIndividualRepository implements IndividualsRepository{

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JdbcIndividualRepository.class);

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public JdbcIndividualRepository(DataSource jdbcDataSource) {
    LOG.info("JDBCRepo arg constructor");
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(jdbcDataSource);
}

@Override
public Individual save(Individual save) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Individual(idIndividual, Name) VALUES(?,?)";
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql, save.getId(), save.getName());
    return save;
}

@Override
public void delete(String key) {
    String sql = "DELETE FROM Individual WHERE idIndividual=?";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, key);
}

@Override
public Individual findById(String key) {
    String sql = "SELECT i.* FROM Individual i WHERE i.idIndividual=?";
    return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new IndividualRowMapper(), key);
}

@Override
public List<Individual> findAll() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Individual";
    return new LinkedList<Individual>(this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new IndividualRowMapper()));
}

}
```

Then I register the jdbc configuration in the initializer class when creating the root context of the application as follows:

```
 private WebApplicationContext createRootContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

    rootContext.register(CoreConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class, JdbcConfiguration.class);
    rootContext.refresh();

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");

    return rootContext;
}
```

However, the Tomcat server wont run because it can't autowire the class MySQLDataSourceConfiguration.

Anyone knows what the problem might be? I can give more details on the code, but the question is already really large.

Appreciate any kind of help!
Cheers

**EDIT**

Solved changing the JdbcConfiguration class to:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:/services.properties")
@Import( { MySQLDataSourceConfiguration.class })
public class JdbcConfiguration {

    @Autowired 
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Inject 
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
        public JdbcTemplate setupJdbcTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
           return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        }

    @Bean
    public IndividualsRepository createRepo(){
    return new JdbcIndividualRepository(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: might be your `JdbcConfiguration` class is hierarchically low than `MySQLDataSourceConfiguration` class. Try by placing `JdbcConfiguration` class in upper hierarchy than `MySQLDataSourceConfiguration` or by copying `@Bean public DataSource dataSource()` method in `JdbcConfiguration` class.

Comment: I don't like your import. I'd just call it out on the context.register.  But probably your real problem is that you've tagged MySQLDataSourceConfiguration with a @Profile("mySQL").  Try adding to your Context: rootContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("mySQL");

Comment: Can you, also, post the stacktrace (complete one)? If you worry about the size of the post, use [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: Remove `@Autowired 
         private DataSourceConfiguration dataSourceConfiguration;` (that's not how it's supposed to be used), instead add to the same class `@Autowired DataSource dataSource;` and use it like `return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);`

Comment: Thanks for the replys. Here is the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/JEmyfCZS

Comment: I tried it but the problem persists. I think I am making a mess of the classes. I am not being able to get the full stack trace in a file I don't know why (I am using Windows atm)

Comment: That stack trace shows "build failed". Is there anything else that's being printed out before the stack trace (which is not very informative)?.

Comment: Well from what I could read (I honestly don't know why the complete stack trave does not get exported to the text file) I still can copy this line 

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [lux.uni.lcsb.msp.restfulws.core.repository.IndividualsRepository] found for
dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

This means that the repositories are not well configured right?

Comment: I have solved the problem. It was indeed a problem with the repository, and the also your first suggestion. I am new to stackoverflow how can I give you reputation? :)

Comment: Try adding `@ComponentScan` to `JdbcConfiguration` class. From what I see in your code the class `JdbcIndividualRepository` is not picked up by anything.

Comment: You can accept my answer below. I just added it based on my comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
@Autowired 
private DataSourceConfiguration dataSourceConfiguration;
```

Because that's not how it's supposed to be used. Instead add to the same class the following:

```
@Autowired DataSource dataSource;
```

and use it like this: `new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);`

Also, try adding @ComponentScan to JdbcConfiguration class. From what I see in your code the class JdbcIndividualRepository is not picked up by anything.

Comment: On top of this I was also missing a Bean with the repository. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your class `JdbcConfiguration`, you are trying to autowire `DataSourceConfiguration`. I'm not really sure if that's possible - typically you should try to autwire the `DataSource`, not the `DataSourceConfiguration`.

```
@Import( { MySQLDataSourceConfiguration.class })
public class JdbcConfiguration {

    @Autowired 
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate setupJdbcTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
```

Also if you have several `DataSource`s and you're using Spring profiles to separate them, it's easier to provide all the `DataSource` beans in one file and annotate each bean with a different profile:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @Profile("Test")
    public DataSource devDataSource() {
        .... configure data source
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("Prod")
    public DataSource prodDataSource() {
        ... configure data source
    }
```

Comment: Yes I wanted to use profiles because I would eventually have several datasources, but I can remove them for the moment.
Importing the configuration class and AAutowiring the DataSource does not solve the problem however. Thank you for the reply!